# Checking previous X rows in an IF clause

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with daily reports for given units that can be simplified to:

```
Unit | Status | Day
1    | On     | 10 March 2016
2    | On     | 10 March 2016
3    | On     | 10 March 2016
4    | On     | 10 March 2016
1    | Off    | 11 March 2016
2    | On     | 11 March 2016
3    | On     | 11 March 2016
4    | On     | 11 March 2016
.
.
.
```

I'm looking to query which units have reported 'Off' for the last 7 days but not really sure how to do it. I would like the query to be something like

```
SELECT 
    Unit, 
    Status,
    CASE WHEN([all 7 previous days were 'Off']) THEN 'Dead' ELSE 'Alive' END
FROM unit_table a
WHERE Day = '15 Sept 2016'
```

How could I do that IF clause? Something like

```
CASE WHEN(SELECT COUNT(SELECT * FROM unit_table b WHERE DAY > '08 Sept 2016' AND Status = 'Off' AND b.Unit = a.Unit) > 7)
```

maybe?

I'm aware that 'DAY > '08 Sept 2016'' won't work natively, there's some internal functions used for comparing and updating dates. This is there just for explanatory purposes.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Note: there is no `IF` in sql. In this case (*maybe*) you could use a `case WHEN ...`, though.

Comment: Done, it's using Snowflake.
@wildplasser thanks for the correction - not sure why I put IF. Would have sworn there was one...updating now

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, I'm thinking something like this:

```
select u.unit
from unit_table u
where date >= '2016-09-15' - interval '6 day'
group by u.unit
having count(distinct case when status = 'Off' then day end) = 7;
```

I'm not intimately familiar with Snowflake, but the syntax might look like:

```
select u.unit
from unit_table u
where date >= dateadd(day, -6, CURRENT_DATE)
group by u.unit
having count(distinct case when u.status = 'Off' then day end) = 7;
```

Answer (score 1):

Gordon, thanks for the answer, your second query should work. Small correction - `date >=`  should probably be `day >=`.

The queries with `DISTINCT` can often be slower (due to duplicate elimination), so if it is guaranteed that for one unit/day combination there is only 1 record, removing it will work.

If it's possible to have more than 1 record per unit per day, Gordon's query will report the unit as dead if it reported `Off` at least once per day (even if there were some `On` reports). If one wants logic where the unit only reported `Off` in the last 7 days, here's an alternative

```
select u.unit
from unit_table u
where day >= dateadd(day, -6, CURRENT_DATE)
group by u.unit
having count(nullif(u.status, 'Off')) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

### If you always have 1 entry per day with no gaps:

The [WINDOW Frame](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html#window-frame-syntax-and-usage) version version of [COUNT_IF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count_if.html) ( COUNT with a nested IFF can also be used), solves this problem:

With this great CTE of data to use:

```
WITH table_data(unit, status, day) AS (
    SELECT column1, column2, column3::date FROM VALUES
        (1, 'On', '2016-03-10'),
        (1, 'On', '2016-03-11'),
        (1, 'On', '2016-03-12'),
        (1, 'On', '2016-03-13'),
        (1, 'On', '2016-03-14'),
        (1, 'On', '2016-03-15'),
        (1, 'On', '2016-03-16'),
        (1, 'On', '2016-03-17'),
        (1, 'On', '2016-03-18'),
    
        (2, 'Off', '2016-03-10'),
        (2, 'Off', '2016-03-11'),
        (2, 'Off', '2016-03-12'),
        (2, 'Off', '2016-03-13'),
        (2, 'Off', '2016-03-14'),
        (2, 'Off', '2016-03-15'),
        (2, 'Off', '2016-03-16'),
        (2, 'Off', '2016-03-17'),
        (2, 'Off', '2016-03-18'),
    
        (3, 'Off', '2016-03-10'),
        (3, 'Off', '2016-03-11'),
        (3, 'Off', '2016-03-12'),
        (3, 'Off', '2016-03-13'),
        (3, 'Off', '2016-03-14'),
        (3, 'On', '2016-03-15'),
        (3, 'Off', '2016-03-16'),
        (3, 'Off', '2016-03-17'),
        (3, 'Off', '2016-03-18')
)
```

We can use:

```
SELECT *
    ,COUNT_IF(status = 'Off') over (PARTITION BY unit ORDER BY day ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as c_count_if_off
   ,IFF(c_count_if_off = 7, 'Dead', 'Alive') AS seven_day_status
FROM table_data
ORDER BY 1,3;
```

and get:

| UNIT | STATUS | DAY | C_COUNT_IF_OFF | SEVEN_DAY_STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | On | 2016-03-10 | 0 | Alive |
| 1 | On | 2016-03-11 | 0 | Alive |
| 1 | On | 2016-03-12 | 0 | Alive |
| 1 | On | 2016-03-13 | 0 | Alive |
| 1 | On | 2016-03-14 | 0 | Alive |
| 1 | On | 2016-03-15 | 0 | Alive |
| 1 | On | 2016-03-16 | 0 | Alive |
| 1 | On | 2016-03-17 | 0 | Alive |
| 1 | On | 2016-03-18 | 0 | Alive |
| 2 | Off | 2016-03-10 | 1 | Alive |
| 2 | Off | 2016-03-11 | 2 | Alive |
| 2 | Off | 2016-03-12 | 3 | Alive |
| 2 | Off | 2016-03-13 | 4 | Alive |
| 2 | Off | 2016-03-14 | 5 | Alive |
| 2 | Off | 2016-03-15 | 6 | Alive |
| 2 | Off | 2016-03-16 | 7 | Dead |
| 2 | Off | 2016-03-17 | 7 | Dead |
| 2 | Off | 2016-03-18 | 7 | Dead |
| 3 | Off | 2016-03-10 | 1 | Alive |
| 3 | Off | 2016-03-11 | 2 | Alive |
| 3 | Off | 2016-03-12 | 3 | Alive |
| 3 | Off | 2016-03-13 | 4 | Alive |
| 3 | Off | 2016-03-14 | 5 | Alive |
| 3 | On | 2016-03-15 | 5 | Alive |
| 3 | Off | 2016-03-16 | 6 | Alive |
| 3 | Off | 2016-03-17 | 6 | Alive |
| 3 | Off | 2016-03-18 | 6 | Alive |

The COUNT_IF `COUNT_IF(status = 'Off')` is the same as `COUNT(IFF(status = 'Off',1,null))` or `SUM(IFF(status = 'Off',1,0))`

And the whole thing can be mashed together into a single line:

```
SELECT *
   ,IFF(COUNT_IF(status = 'Off') over (PARTITION BY unit ORDER BY day ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) = 7, 'Dead', 'Alive') AS seven_day_status
FROM table_data
ORDER BY 1,3;
```

### If you have multiple entries per day AND/OR gaps:

I would use [MATCH_RECONGNIZE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/match_recognize.html) of some other manual form of edge detection.